# Are ActiveRecord transactions just 1 round trip to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I have a bunch of queries that I am executing, wrapped in an Activerecord transaction, are all those queries sent to the database in 1 round trip (ie all queries sent to db, and response sent back), or does each query take up 1 trip each?

Example Code:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do   
      queries.each do |query|
           ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
      end
end
```

If the latter, is there a way to force all the queries inside a transaction to be executed in 1 round trip?

Comment: are your queries all strings of raw SQL?

Answer (score 5):

The `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` call will make two calls to the database:

- One to tell the database to start a transaction.
- And another one when the block exits to tell the database to commit or rollback the transaction.

Each `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` call also talk to the database. This has to happen as the queries that you `execute` might raise exceptions or return useful data. In general, each SQL statement is a separate call (i.e. roundtrip) to the database.

Only one database *connection* will be used though.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will prevent you from executing multiple queries in a trip (which does mitigate some nasty SQL injection possibilities such as [little bobby tables](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=327%3a_Exploits_of_a_Mom);)

If your DB supports it, you could in theory send it all in one go:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(["BEGIN",*query,"COMMIT",""]*";\n")
```

**Note the "in theory."   Don't actually try to do it this way.**

---

If someone is wondering what's going on there.

query = Your array of queries

arr= `["BEGIN",*query,"COMMIT",""]`  just flattens the query into the array.

`arr*";\n"`   is the same as `arr.join(";\n")`     The blank at the end of the array provides the trailing ";" for the COMMIT.

This is fun for something like Ruby Golf, but don't use it in production.   You'll only be hurting those that try to read your code in the future (even the future you.)